# Data Structures - Linked list library in C

Tags: c, linked-list, structure

I'm new to C so I'm seeking help because I'm stuck.
After creating a linked-list library, from which I can add, delete and print all the nodes the user wants, I should add to the program an additional function of integer type and return a -1 if the value doesn't exist inside of the linked-list. If the value does exist inside the linked list, it should return the position of the element.

For example in this linked-list (`a -> b -> c -> d -> NULL`) if I want to know the position of `c` it should return me a 3, if I want to know the position of `G` it should return me -1

This is the program I was able to make until now:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct ListNode
{ 
char data;
struct ListNode *nextNode;
};
typedef struct ListNode node;


int main()
   {
    node *startNodePtr= NULL;
    int choice;
    char value;
    printf("\t\t\tLIST OF CHARACTERS\n");
    do
    {
        printf("\n1.Add New Node \t2.Delete Node \t3.Print Current List \t4.QUIT\n\n");//user friendly interface
        scanf("%d",&choice);
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1: printf("Enter Character: ");
                scanf("\n%c",&value);
                insertNode(&startNodePtr,value);//calling the function to add a node
                break;

            case 2: printf("Delete Character: ");
                scanf("\n%c",&value);
                deleteNode(&startNodePtr,value);//calling the function to remove a node
                break;

            case 3: printList(startNodePtr);//calling the function to list the nodes
                break;

            case 4: continue;//if we type 4 it won't show the default answer

            default:printf("\t\tINVALID ANSWER! Please type 1. 2. 3. or 4.\n");// in case we type any other character that is not 1, 2, 3 or 4. In this way the program will not crash
                break;

        }

    } while(choice!=4);//keep adding or deleting nodes until we enter 4 which refers to "QUIT"

return 0;
 }

void insertNode(node **sPtr, char add)//function to add a node
   {
    node *newPtr;
    node *curPtr;
    node *prevPtr;
    newPtr=malloc(sizeof(node));
    newPtr->data=add;
    newPtr->nextNode=NULL;
    prevPtr=NULL;
    curPtr=*sPtr;

    while(curPtr!=NULL)
    {
        prevPtr=curPtr;
        curPtr=curPtr->nextNode;
    }
    if (prevPtr==NULL)
    {
        *sPtr=newPtr;
    }
    else
    {
        prevPtr->nextNode=newPtr;
    }
 }
void deleteNode(node **sPtr, char remove)//function to remove a node
    {
    node *curPtr;
    node *prevPtr;
    curPtr=*sPtr;
    prevPtr=NULL;

   if(curPtr->data==remove)
   {
        *sPtr=curPtr->nextNode;
        free(curPtr);
        return;
}
while (curPtr!=NULL)
{
    if (curPtr->data==remove)
       {prevPtr->nextNode=curPtr->nextNode;
        free(curPtr);
        return;}
    else
       {prevPtr=curPtr;
       curPtr=curPtr->nextNode;}
}
 }


void printList(node *sPtr)//function to list the nodes
{
if (sPtr==NULL)
{
    printf("The list is empty!\n");
}
else
{
    while (sPtr!=NULL)
    {
        printf("\n%c-->", sPtr->data);
        sPtr=sPtr->nextNode;
    }

}   printf("NULL\n\n");

}
```

Comment: OK, so what's the problem?   You already have functions that iterate the list, so...  I can't see the problem at all:(

Comment: @MartinJames Yeah, it sounds stupid but I don't know how I can do to create the function. I can add a case 5. calling the function findFunction(&startNoderPtr, integer) and adding an integer variable in the structure, and then?. I'm a little bit confused

Comment: Try researching maybe "traverse linked list in C get value". I think you should put in more effort of trying to solve the problem than just saying he is my problem can you do it for me.

Comment: @sebenalern You are right on saying that but I wouldn't say I didn't put effort on it.The initial problem was to make the entire program;as I said I'm completely new to C.I took this class in January and I learned how to do structures and linked-libraries one week ago.I literally sat for 4 hours brainstorming and trying to figure out how to make it work.Then I was able to make it. I did all the program until that point and then I couldn't figure out what and how to proceed. Instead of waiting 2 days and ask my teacher, I ask to someone of you. This forum was made to help each other, didn't it?

Comment: Okay, the thing is you didn't tell us you tried anything and the question wasn't very specific, like I said the question was posed as this is my problem can you solve it.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding by us humans: 1) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line.  2) indent consistently.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  un-indent before every closing brace '}'.  suggest using 4 spaces for each indent level as that is wide enough to be visible even with variable width fonts.  Note never use tabs for indenting.

Comment: suggest displaying the menu on successive lines rather than on one very long (which will probably wrap) line.  Suggest displaying the menu as one possible selection per line (humans have a much easier time seeing things aligned vertically the seeing things strung out horizontally

Comment: follow the axiom: only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.   This includes not hiding a closing brace '}' at the end of a line, behind another statement.  Nor hiding a statement after a opening brace '{'.

Comment: when calling and of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the posted code does not cleanly compile.  Amongst other things, the posted code is missing prototypes for the sub functions.

Comment: when calling any of the memory allocation family (malloc, calloc, realloc), always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the case 4: should have a body of `break;`, not `continue:`

Comment: the function: `insertNode()`,  1) can corrupt the linked list of the call to `malloc()` rails.  2) allows for duplicate entries to be created in the linked list, which, of itself is ok, but will result in incorrect node counts when searching for a specific data.

Comment: the function: `insertNode()` would be better named as `appendNode()`

Answer (score 0):

You have basically solved it already, you just have to count the number of iterations until you find the correct element.

```
int search(struct ListNode *node, char data) {
    int position = 1;
    // List is empty
    if (node == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    while (node != NULL) {
        if (node->data == data) {
            return position;
        }
        position++;
        node = node->nextNode;
    }
    // Element was not in the list
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: mmmh, it looks good but for some reason it gives me error. it says "unkown type name ListNode"

Comment: @Leandro `ListNode` replace with `struct ListNode`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY 
'case 4: search(&startNodePtr, value);
  break;' 
 'int search(ListNode *node, char data)' 

it gives me error if I call the function in that way

Comment: @Leandro `case 4: search(startNodePtr, value); break;`,  `int search(struct ListNode *node, char data)`  : Because it is not changed the List, So `&` is not necessary.

Comment: You are right,I didn't notice. Now it works thank you. But it is not printing out any value if I enter 4, it just repeat the loop as nothing as happened

Comment: @Leandro Like this: `int pos;` .... `case 4: puts("input search value:"); scanf("\n%c",&value); pos = search(startNodePtr, value); if(pos == -1) puts("Not found!"); else printf("Position of %c is %d\n", value, pos);break;`

Comment: I think the solution should `ListNode` with `node`, since we should use the defined type, like the other functions. Of course the variable name `node` has to change, too.

Comment: Thank you very much guys. I was able to make it work following @BLUEPIXY and Fjotten tips. I apprecciated it. Do I have to post the complete program?

Comment: @Leandro  _Do I have to post the complete program?_ I think that it don't need.

Comment: @Leandro If you got it working, I would kindly appreciate you accepting the answer.